# Работа функции replace

Tags: python

Например

```
a='mama'
a= a.replace(a[-1],'x')
print a
```

Почему получается не mamx, a mxmx?

Comment: `a[-1]` - возвращает символ 'а', который передаётся как аргумент функции `replace` и её вызов становится эквавалентен replace('a','x')

Answer (score 6):

Функция replace получает на вход 2 аргумента:

1) Какой символ надо заменить;

2) На какой символ надо заменить.

Функция применяется к строке. Вы извлекаете срез (т.е. подстроку) из строки 'mama'. Результат работы этого среза - символ 'a'. Затем вы применяете функцию replace ко всей строке. Т.е. просите python в строке 'mama' найти все символы 'a' и заменить их на 'x'.

Answer (score 1):

Вот как получить 'mamx'

```
>>> a = 'mama'
>>> b = a[:-1] + 'x'
>>> print b
mamx
```